# Where to find the environmental variables file in CentOS

Tags: environment-variables, centos6.6

Where can I find the envvars configuration file (if there are any) in CentOS?

I know in Ubuntu, Apache2, I can find it from `/etc/apache2/envvars`

I've tried the command,

`export EXAMPLE=value` command. Does it require server restart to get it affected?

Please advise, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global Environment variable file is :- `/etc/profile`

Local Environment Variable ( User Specific ) file is :- `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: There are some existing environmental variables, which I get using PHP `getenv()` function. I would like to know where this is saved in.

Comment: you can use `set` command and this will list all the env variables in your current session.

Comment: I'm able to add this through WHM, but need to know where does it get saved.

Comment: through getenv() function you get the value of environment variable that are already stored.

Comment: Agree, would like to know where does these environmental variables get stored? Like in Apache2 `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Comment: I gave you answer. In /etc/profile

Comment: Thanks, I was able to add the env var through WHM, but curious to know where its getting saved. The ones added from WHM is not getting saved in /etc/profile. Any idea?

Comment: Check /etc/httpd/sysconfig file for that. Apache Env variables are stored there.

Comment: `/etc/httpd/sysconfig` It doesn't exist!!

Comment: My bad.. It is `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

Comment: Don't know whats happening, the file `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` doesn't exist too!!

Comment: you have apache installed .. (htttpd) If yes than it must be there

Comment: These are only environment variable files in CentOS. `/etc/profile`,`/etc/profile.d/`,`~/.bash_profile` and `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`. And some commands like `env` and `set` used to view env variables. If you don't find your variables in these than it might be possible they exists at runtime. The kernel stores the list of environment variables and their values for each process. A virtual file exists at `/proc/<pid>/environ
`

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm new to Linux, it was done by someone else and I'm figuring it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Rehdat Equiv to /etc/apache2/envvars**

The Redhat and Centos equiv to /etc/apache2/envvars is `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

The other answers are also correct if you are ok with the variables being truly global.  Using `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` will keep the variables confined to httpd.

As [Siddharth sharma](https://serverfault.com/users/329044/siddharth-sharma) pointed out, you can also set the environment variable in the apache config.

e.g.

```
SetEnv TMPDIR /var/www/.cgitmp
```

Comment: The file `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` doesn't exist!!

Comment: How did you install apache?  If you used `yum install httpd` then you most certainly would have that file.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm new to Linux, it was done by someone else and I'm figuring it out. Thanks :)

Comment: If someone removed the file by mistake, you can put it back.  By default, it just contains `LANG=C` and a commented out `#OPTIONS=`

Comment: As @Siddharth sharma said, _If you don't find your variables in these than it might be possible they exists at runtime. The kernel stores the list of environment variables and their values for each process_. I was able to find the environ files under different process. 

How can I find out whether the apache runs on httpd or litespeed? I could see both processes running. Confused.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `set` and you will see all env variables of your session.
`export` acts immideately, you don't need any extra actions.